# NoraUI - Null Pointer Exception while using a customDataProvider as Input and Output

Tags: java, noraui

I have a problem when i try to use a CustomDataProvider as Input and Output. At some point in the scenario, a NPE exception is thrown.

**Edit 1 :** I've already read [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) : I understand what is a NPE and how to resolve it. What i do not understand in my case is why there is one happening at that moment of the execution and with this particular object in my case. I am not an expert of the NoraUI Framework. When I looked at existing dataProvider they never manipulate indexData object, so I did not too. I do not know how they are handled and when they are initialized. That is why I am asking the question of why it is happening at this moment and if I forgot something to someone with more experience. Sorry if it was not clear. it is a question more related to the NoraUI Framework than a pure Java one.

**The Exception :**

The scenarioInitiator execution is going well with the CustomDataProvider : the data is well generated and written on the Gherkin. But just at the beginning of the launch of the scenario, the exception is thrown :

```
[2017-08-16 15:37:28]: ********************************************************************************************************
[2017-08-16 15:37:28]: *                                                                                                      *
[2017-08-16 15:37:28]: *   Scénario: [@scenario] étape 1 sur 0 avec 0 erreur(s) et 0 alerte(s). Il reste 0s   *
[2017-08-16 15:37:28]: *                                                                                                      *
[2017-08-16 15:37:28]: ********************************************************************************************************

Failed scenarios:
steps/scenarios/scenario.feature:4 # Scenario: scenario

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
28 Steps (28 skipped)
5m52.930s

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at noraui.exception.Result$Success.<init>(Result.java:32)
    at noraui.application.steps.CucumberHooks.setUpScenario(CucumberHooks.java:44)
```

With a little more research with the debug, it seems the exact line that is provoking the Exception is the condition of the **for loop** in the first constructor of the **noraui.exception.Result$Success** object :

```
public static class Success<O> extends Result {
        private final O object;
        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Success.class.getName());

        public Success(O object, String message) throws TechnicalException {
            this.object = object;
            this.message = message;
            for (Integer i : Context.getDataInputProvider().getIndexData(Context.getCurrentScenarioData()).getIndexes()) {
                Context.getDataOutputProvider().writeSuccessResult(i);
            }
            logger.info(message + " [" + success() + "]");
        }

        public O success() {
            Optional<O> o = Optional.ofNullable(object);
            return o.isPresent() ? o.get() : null;
        }
    }
```

I suppose it have something to do with the **IndexData** that are declared in the DataProvider Object (which is extended by CustomDataProvider which is in turn extended by my customDataProvider). But I just can't see why it would fail as in my case I used the super method, just as the other common DataProvider (Excel, DB, etc).

**Custom Data Provider :**

My custom data provider launch multiples query with some being modified depending of what the first query return. The final result of those queries is stored into the `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataTable` variable. the row of the data are the following : `| Offer | Product | Items | Results |`

**So my question is :**

Why does using my custom data provider throw this NPE while with other DataProvider, it does not. As i do not see any of them having custom way of handling DataIndex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @AMallal, No duplicate post, is it specific to NoraUi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to occur because of this part of code:

```
getIndexData(Context.getCurrentScenarioData())
```

getIndexData returns null for the current retrieved Context.getCurrentScenarioData();

If you created an DataInputProvider, you should extend your class from `CommonDataProvider` and override `getModel()` method as following:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public Class<Model> getModel(String modelPackages) throws TechnicalException {
    return null;
}
```

The `getNbLines()` method should be also be redefined by returning the number of data lines used as input (including column names line).

In fact, these two methods are required in `Context` class to initialize scenarios data indexes that are used for writing results.

Hoping this helps

Comment: Thanks you very much, overiding the getModel() method solved this issue. As I do not use model in my project, i did not think I had anything to do with this one.

I also did a mistake in the getNbLines() method, I was returning the number of row of data without the column names row.